# Transfer Values from a 2-dimensional-Array to an other 2-dimensional-Array / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why is every single value of array2 4 (the last value of array1).
I get this problems only with 2d-arrays.

```
 var array1 = [
      new Array(4).fill(1),
      new Array(4).fill(2),
      new Array(4).fill(3),
      new Array(4).fill(4),
];
function test() {
  var array2 = new Array(4).fill(new Array(4).fill(-1));

  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array1[0].length; j++) {
      array2[i][j] = array1[i][j];
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array1[0].length; j++) {
      console.log("index: " + i + "," + j + " value: " + array2[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill _"The fill method is a mutable method, it will change this object itself, and return it, not just return a copy of it.

When the fill method gets passed an object, it will copy the passed object, and fill the array with a reference to the copy."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

You're passing a single array to `fill`, and array values are accessed by reference, so technically the inner arrays are *references* to the same array.

#### The Long Answer

The reason why *all* of the values in the second array is because of the way it's being created in the first place:

```
var array2 = new Array(4).fill(new Array(4).fill(-1));
```

In this line, you're creating a new array with a length of 4, and then "filling" each index in that array with the *output* from this statement:

```
new Array(4).fill(-1)
```

That block isn't run for each value that is being "filled", but rather the *value* that is passed as the argument for `fill` is used as the value for each index. This works fine with simpler values, like strings and integers, but objects and arrays are accessed by reference in JavaScript, so each time you modify the value of an index of one nested array, you're modifying the value of that index for all four of the nested arrays.

So when you do something like this:

```
array2[0][0] = 3
```

`array2` will end up with this value:

```
[ [ 3, -1, -1, -1],
  [ 3, -1, -1, -1],
  [ 3, -1, -1, -1],
  [ 3, -1, -1, -1] ]
```

In order to change it so it is not done by reference, you can use the spread operator and build the array that way.

```
var array2 = [...Array(4)].map(_ => [...Array(4)])
```

If you're not working in an environment where you can use the spread operators, you can also loop over the values, which will execute its the `new Array` statement for *each* value:

```
var array2 = new Array(4);
for (var i=0; i<array2.length; i++) {
    array2[i] = new Array(4).fill(-1);
}
```